# Unable to build extended domain with WLS, Forms, Reports: expected directories not created

Tags: oracle, installation, configuration, weblogic12c

I am in the middle of building a 4-node application layer using WLS, Oracle Forms and Oracle Reports.  I have built an ADMIN node and successfully built the RCU and have run config.sh.
I fully defined the entire domain (all 4 nodes) while running config.sh.  I have copied and moved the domain definition to the 2nd node using pack & unpack.
When I attempt to install and build on the 2nd node (ADMIN does not run here), and run Forms and/or Reports for the first time, many directories are automatically created.
But some I expect to be created are missing.
For example:
$DOMAIN_HOME/config/fmwconfig/components/FORMS/instances/forms2/server/
did not get created.

What step did I miss here that results in some of the necessary directories not being created?

Comment: After you have created the domain on the first (admin) node, copy the domain folder on other nodes.

Comment: That is done using the pack & unpack.  Did that.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the FORMS SystemComponents are not installed in the new instance locations under `<domain_name>/config/fmwconfig/components/FORMS/<instance>` and the FORMS components are not carried across by the *pack* command.

Re-running the config wizard will allow you to install the components on the new instances.

Alternatively, the instance definitions can be added on the Admin Server with WLST in offline mode only:

```
readDomain('<$DOMAIN_HOME>')
print('Create FORMS SystemComponent '+'forms2')
cd('/')
create('forms2', 'SystemComponent')
cd('/SystemComponent/'+'forms2')
cmo.setComponentType('FORMS')
set('Machine', machineName)

updateDomain()
closeDomain()
```

The above only works if the Managed Server shares the domain's filesystem with the Admin Server.

Also see:
https://github.com/galiacheng/oracle-forms-reports-weblogic-on-azure#create-managed-servers-and-forms-component